# Responsive div height on div overlap

Tags: html, css, responsive

[image]

I am trying to do the following in the image: The top div will contain text of variable length. The bottom div is fixed in place and should respond by resizing its height to avoid the overlap, while overflowing the text if needed. Is there a way to do this in CSS? I have attached the jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/0nr3g7kq/123/

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 145px;
  position: relative;
}

.content1,
.content2 {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: blue;
  margin: 1px;
  width: 268px;
}

.content2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.desc {}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="content1">
    <span class="title">
          This top div should compress the bottom div downwards without changing its position.
        </span>
  </div>
  <div class="content2">
    <span class="desc">
           This bottom div should respond by being compressed and show 1 less visible line with text overflow but not change position
        </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `min-width:268px;` to `.content1, .content2` it will solve current problem

Comment: That didn't seem to solve my problem. Nothing has changed. I need a way for the second div to respond to the first

Answer (score 0):

put `max-width:` instead of `width:` in `.content1, .content2` and remove `.content2 { position: absolute; bottom: 20px; }`